# Application_PreRequestHandlerExecute redirect during 404 page not found

Tags: c#, asp.net, redirect, global-asax

I am trying to log referrers from several domains I own which do a 301 permanent redirect to our secure site. So I have two Web Sites via IIS.

http://www.cool_domain.com/ would redirect to https://www.real_domain.com/ as example. During this process, I want to log, and then redirect during the PreRequestHandlerExecute method.

If the page is NOT FOUND (404), Application_PreRequestHandlerExecute does not fire. If it DOES exist, it fires just fine.

```
void Application_PreRequestHandlerExecute(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Context.Handler is IRequiresSessionState || Context.Handler is IReadOnlySessionState)
    {
        LogPage(Request);
        HttpContext.Current.Response.RedirectPermanent("https://www.real_domain.com/", true);
    }
}
```

How can I get this to fire during 404's as well?

Answer (score 0):

Stupid mistake, and I should have known... in case anyone else runs into this, and has a brainfart as well, the global.asax will not execute a 404 error unless it's a .net page (aspx, etc.).